# Build failed when deploy angular application - How to upgrade node.js version in aws?

Tags: amazon-ec2

How to upgrade node.js file on buildspec.yml? I just upgraded node.js : 12 but build failed. What is the steps with upgrade node.js on github angular application code and also in aws.

```
[Container] 2021/06/14 15:42:43 Phase complete: INSTALL State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2021/06/14 15:42:43 Phase context status code:  Message: 
[Container] 2021/06/14 15:42:43 Entering phase PRE_BUILD
[Container] 2021/06/14 15:42:43 Phase complete: PRE_BUILD State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2021/06/14 15:42:43 Phase context status code:  Message: 
[Container] 2021/06/14 15:42:43 Entering phase BUILD
[Container] 2021/06/14 15:42:43 Running command echo Build started
Build started

[Container] 2021/06/14 15:42:43 Running command ng build --configuration=test
Node.js version v10.19.0 detected.
The Angular CLI requires a minimum Node.js version of either v12.14 or v14.15.

Please update your Node.js version or visit https://nodejs.org/ for additional instructions.


[Container] 2021/06/14 15:42:43 Command did not exit successfully ng build --configuration=test exit status 3
[Container] 2021/06/14 15:42:43 Phase complete: BUILD State: FAILED
[Container] 2021/06/14 15:42:43 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: ng build --configuration=test. Reason: exit status 3
[Container] 2021/06/14 15:42:43 Entering phase POST_BUILD
[Container] 2021/06/14 15:42:43 Phase complete: POST_BUILD State: SUCCEEDED
[Container] 2021/06/14 15:42:43 Phase context status code:  Message: 
[Container] 2021/06/14 15:42:43 Expanding base directory path: dist*
[Container] 2021/06/14 15:42:43 Assembling file list
[Container] 2021/06/14 15:42:43 Expanding dist*
[Container] 2021/06/14 15:42:43 Phase complete: UPLOAD_ARTIFACTS State: FAILED
[Container] 2021/06/14 15:42:43 Phase context status code: CLIENT_ERROR Message: no matching base directory path found for dist*
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your build script to pin the version to get your build working.

npm install -g @angular/cli@11.2.12

But you need to consider working on upgrading your Angular version that is compatible with newer versions of Node.